# I get an error message when I try to update any app

Tags: macos, ios, applications, software-update, accounts

I have about 40 apps that need to be updated, mostly iOS but also some OS X. Some are free and some are ones I bought previously. I have only ever had one apple account and am still using it, but when I try to update any app I get e following error "You can not update this software since you have not owned the major version of this software". I can however download new apps. My account is based in Canada, I am currently in Australia on holidays for 5 weeks.

How can I update the apps while I'm here?

Comment: Your current location does not matter, as you are using the Canadian App Store. Your question is not very clear; are you trying to update your iOS apps through iPhone/iPad or OS X applications through a MacBook? Is your credit card information verified correctly/up-to-date? If yes and if on OS X, try signing out of App Store and signing back-in and try again. [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2365071?start=0&tstart=0) is a discussion that is caused by multiple accounts. Have you ever logged-in using another account into the App Store on your computer?

Comment: I get the same error when trying to update iOS apps through iPhone/iPad and when trying to update osx apps through my MacBook. I have never had or signed in with another account. I previously had an Australian credit card attached to the account, which it will not let me add to the Canadian App Store. I now have some gift card credit attached to my account.

Comment: Anyone able to help?

Comment: Guessing that you are having a problem related to the credit card. I think your best bet is to contact Apple support or the Genius bar folks (if there is an Apple Store close by).